# Why is there no a border on this GtkFrame?

Tags: c, gtk, frame, gtk3

I'm reading tutorials on `GtkFrame`, I have compile some code examples, but unlike screnhoot of the tutorial, but my program using `GtkFrame` don't have a border.

The following code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main( int   argc,
          char *argv[] )
{
  /* GtkWidget is the storage type for widgets */
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *frame;
  GtkWidget *button;
  GtkWidget *label;
  gint i;

  /* Initialise GTK */
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  /* Create a new window */
  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Frame Example");

  /* Here we connect the "destroy" event to a signal handler */ 
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "destroy",
                      G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  gtk_widget_set_size_request(window, 300, 300);
  /* Sets the border width of the window. */
  gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 10);

  label = gtk_label_new("foo");

  /* Create a Frame */
  frame = gtk_frame_new(NULL);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(frame), label);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request(frame, 30, 30);

  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), frame);

  /* Set the frame's label */
  gtk_frame_set_label( GTK_FRAME(frame), "GTK Frame Widget" );

  /* Set the style of the frame */
  gtk_frame_set_shadow_type( GTK_FRAME(frame), GTK_SHADOW_ETCHED_OUT);

  gtk_widget_show(frame);

  /* Display the window */
  gtk_widget_show (window);

  /* Enter the event loop */
  gtk_main ();

  return(0);
}
/* example-end */
```

Generate the program:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Hm, interestingly, I get a border with gtk2, but not with gtk3. Maybe it has to do with styling?

Comment: @Ancurio: I did a lot of googling and have read from top to down the "devhelp" looking for something like set border/gtk frame style, but no luck. I have no idea why it was removed or do we have a bug into our gtk+3? (sorry for bad english, not my native language)

Comment: Well, looks like it was removed in Gtk3 http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/GtkFrame.html ideas for replacement?

Comment: where does it say it was removed??

Comment: Compare the images http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkFrame.html and http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/GtkFrame.html

Comment: Yeah but it still says "with a decorative frame". I googled around a bit and it seems to be an issue with some themeing engines. Otherwise there wouldn't really be much point to the GtkFrame class anymore.

Comment: Really, the description text is the same. Unlike to images, that's strange. In fact, I haven't noticed any changes into documentation; looks like exactly the same document. No idea to what to do. Do you know any widgets equivalent? I'm considering back to gtk2..

Comment: Do you need anything specific from gtk3? Because gtk2 is still widely supported and probably will be for the coming years. Also, I just checked, and in the screenshot for [3.2](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkFrame.html) the frame is still there, whereas it is missing in [3.4](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/GtkFrame.html). I recall that a whole lot changed in regards to CSS styling between those two versions, so it might be a themeing issue after all

Comment: No, I don't need really any gtk3-specific. Thanks for your time and for finding this screenshot. I'II try gtk 3.2, if still no luck, back to gtk 2.x.

Comment: I don't think going back to GTK 2 just for that is a good idea. GTK 2 will be less and less supported, and there are already plans for GTK 4 (Cluter integration for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is GTK bug [659926](http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=659926). However, it seems this is mostly due to the fact that the Adwaita theme (default GNOME 3 theme) ignores the frames, so maybe changing the theme (using gnome-tweak-tool, if you want to use a GUI) will do the trick. However I think frames are abused in many GUIs and often lead to ugly interfaces, as they add visual clutter. Less is better.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I'm sorry for don't given 50+ before, I forget to click on this button.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the shadow type of the frame?

```
gtk_frame_set_shadow_type (GTK_FRAME (frame), GTK_SHADOW_TYPE_IN);
```

Comment: Did you mean `GTK_SHADOW_IN` instead of `GTK_SHADOW_TYPE_IN`? yeah, I have tried it. Makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use CSS.

CSS file example:

```
frame#LINMONI_Frame_Inactiv {
    color: grey;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width: 8px;
    border-color: grey;
    background-color: white;
}
```

and after create gtkwidgets:

```
    GtkCssProvider *provider;
    GdkScreen *screen;
    GdkDisplay *display;

    provider = gtk_css_provider_new();
    display = gdk_display_get_default();
    screen = gdk_display_get_default_screen(display);
    gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen(screen, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(provider),GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);
    gsize bytes_read;
    gsize bytes_written;
    GError *error = NULL;
    if (!gtk_css_provider_load_from_path(provider,g_filename_to_utf8("yourcssfilename.css, csCompleteFileName.GetLength(),&bytes_read, &bytes_written, &error), NULL)){
        if (error){
            Trace_Error("gtk_css_provider_load_from_path=%s\n",error->message);
        }
    }
    g_object_unref(provider);
```